# C++ pass newly created vector as parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, c++17

If I have a function that expects a `std::pair` or `std::array` for example, I can do the following:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <string>

void foo(std::array<int,5>){}
void bar(std::pair<int,std::string>){}

int main(){

foo({1,2,3,4,5});
bar(std::make_pair(1, "test"));

}
```

What would be a similar way of passing a `std::vector` as a parameter?
Is there a way to pass a `std::vector` that is being created in the same line as the call to a function that expects it as a parameter?

How to achieve the requested with the following:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void testVector(std::vector<std::string> &t){}

int main(){

std::vector<std::string> boring; // I don't want to create a vector like this
testVector(boring);       // this works obviously

testVector({"hello"});    // this does not work
testVector(std::vector<std::string>(){"test"}); // does not work either

}
```

I just edited the question because I wanted to pass a reference. But I think there is no way of passing a reference to a vector that was instantiated that way right?

Comment: Your last example should work if you get rid of the `()`; they have no business being there at all. Your penultimate example should also work.

Comment: [The first "not working" example compiles.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ezvG944o9)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/drdTYjd41 You can see plainly that your last two examples work fine. The last one required fixing the bad syntax. It works from C++11 and up.

Comment: Fixing the three obvious typos in the code (the lack of `#include <string>`, the return type of `main`, and the extra `()`) [your code builds fine](https://godbolt.org/z/7zKfn3o4W). If you have problems, then please try to create a proper [mre] to show us, as well as copy-pasting the full and complete build output fro the shown example. And also tell us what compiler you're using, and what flags/options you pass to it.

Comment: Yes it works, thank you. I just edited the question because I wanted to pass a reference.  But I think there is no way of passing a reference to a vector that was instantiated that way right?

Comment: Your edit now changes the question ***a lot*** (and I'll bet there's a few duplicates around). You try to pass temporary objects as arguments to the function, and non-constant references can not bind to temporary objects.

Comment: The parameter must also be passed by *const* reference, value, or rvalue reference. Passed by non-const reference, it cannot accept a temporary.

Comment: The recent edit makes your "this works with `std::array`" completely pointless because you're doing different things now.

Comment: For future questions, please remember the [mre] and the build-output of it. Also please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 4):

using

```cpp
void baz(std::vector<int> vec) { … }
```

works:

```cpp
…
baz({1,2,3});
…
```

But: using a plain vector as signature will lead to every function call making a *copy* of the vector. You very rarely actually want that, unless your method actually needs a copy for some reason.

The usual way is to use a reference:

```cpp
void baz_ref(std::vector<int>& vec) { … }
```

which means that now, the function doesn't get a copy, but works on the original vector – but that means your function might have *side effects* that the calling function doesn't expect!

Also, you can't call `baz_ref({1, 2, 3});`, because that would pass a reference to a temporary object.

In cases where your function doesn't need to *modify* the vector:

```cpp
void baz_constref(const std::vector<int>& vec) { … }
```

is the way to go – no copy, trying to modify `vec` won't work. The compiler can beautifully optimize this, and you can also call `baz_constref({1, 2, 3});`.

There's another option: Move semantics, and it *might* be the right thing if your function actually modifies the vector – should that function be the new "owner"? Then, you should move that vector into the function, but the calling function then loses the ability to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your entry point is wrong, it should be `int main` and not `void main`. And the following code works

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void testVector(std::vector<std::string>){}

int main()
{

    std::vector<std::string> boring;
    testVector(boring);

    testVector({"hello"}); // This works
    testVector(std::vector<std::string>{"test"}); // This works too :)
}
```

[Here is the test of the above code](https://onlinegdb.com/V8hspQzpG)

Comment: OP change the details of his/her question recently, so you may consider editing your post.

Comment: I m sorry, I rushed a little bit into this question. I will edit/ delete it if there are duplicates

Comment: @justANewbie I am the OP of this Post

Comment: @L.Gashi Oops. sorry for the mistake. You can say I rushed a little bit into your comment :)